# Hide Custom button on the basis of pick list value not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript, account

I have created one Custom Button same name as "Submit For Approval"  I have choose the behavior as "Execute JavaScript"

I have created one extension class
public class AccountExtensionController
{
   public Id accountId {get;set;}
   public List accountList {get;set;}
   public Boolean hideSubmitForApprovalButton {get;set;}

private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;

```
public AccountExtensionController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
{
    this.standardController = standardController;
    showHideButton();
    system.debug('Check1');
} 
public Boolean showHideButton()
{
    accountId= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    hideSubmitForApprovalButton =false;
    system.debug('Check2'+hideSubmitForApprovalButton );
    accountList =[select id, Ownership from account where id =: accountId];
    if(accountList.size()>0)
        {
            if(accountList[0].Ownership == 'Private' || accountList[0].Ownership  == 'Subsidiary')
            {
                hideSubmitForApprovalButton=true;
                system.debug('Check3'+hideSubmitForApprovalButton );
            }
        }
         system.debug('Check4'+hideSubmitForApprovalButton );
        return hideSubmitForApprovalButton;
}
```

}
VF Class

if ('{!Account.Ownership} == 'Private'' ) hideButton("Submit_For_Approval_Test");
function hideButton(Submit_For_Approval_Test) 
{
  try
  {
    var buttons = parent.document.getElementsByName(btnName);
    for (var i=0; i

Comment: function hideButton(Submit_For_Approval_Test) 
{
  try
  {
    var buttons = parent.document.getElementsByName(btnName);
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    {
      buttons[i].className="btnDisabled ";
      buttons[i].disabled=true;
      buttons[i].type='hidden';
    }
  } 
  catch(e) 
  {
    // var ee = e.message || 0; alert('Error: \n\n'+e+'\n'+ee);
  }
}
</script>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 0):

you can go with the below code too.
In this you can show and hide all possible buttons using CSS and JAVASCRIPT .Passing ownership as a variable in the function

CODE.
CSS CODE
.btnDisabled {display:none;}
.btnEnabled {display:block;}

JAVASCRIPT CODE
function toggleButtons(Ownership) { 
var myButtonClasses = document.getElementById("btnName").classList;
if(Ownership=='Private' ||Ownership=='Subsidiary' ){
 if (myButtonClasses.contains("btnDisabled ")) {
    myButtonClasses.remove("btnEnabled");
 } else {
    myButtonClasses.add("btnDisabled ");
  }
 }
}